# How to spawn slimes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have tried everything from using the slime finder app to the slime finder mod, but so no matter what I do no slimes seem to spawn.

I'm playing on normal difficulty, at layer 13 and I've made a 16X16X3 room; still nothing. 
Does anyone have any tips that I might have missed?

Comment: You know that slimes also spawn in swamp biomes, right?

Comment: How close are you standing to the spawning room?

Answer (score 3):

According to the minecraft wiki, this is there spawn routine:

- Slimes naturally spawn in underground caves and on the surface of Swamp biomes during the night (or superflat worlds)
- In swamps, slimes may spawn at night. They spawn most often on a full moon, and never on a new moon. This can make gathering slimeballs difficult, as it takes over two hours for the moon to cycle.
- They spawn throughout underground caves below level 40. They spawn randomly in 1/10 chunks

I suggest you read up on the wiki, as there are methods for farming them aswell. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could try to find a swamp biome; they always spawn there at night except for new moons, and that is a good spot to look. That would be your best option, unless you want to cheat.